# Ical changes time I put in when making .ics file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, icalendar, datetime-format

I'm having the following problem. I am creating .ics calendar file using icalendar gem (https://github.com/icalendar/icalendar). For example, I write in time like so:

```
def make_ical(email)
  cal = Icalendar::Calendar.new
  cal.event do |e|
    e.dtstart = Icalendar::Values::Datetime.new('20141230T193400')
    e.dtend = Icalendar::Values::Datetime.new('20141230T213400')
    ..
  end
end
```

But when it builds .ics file, it shows different time than what I put in. I suspect it converts it to some kind of time zone. How can I prevent it from doing this? Or maybe there's a way to change initial time so if it must convert, it would convert it correctly. Please help.

`calendar.ics` file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:icalendar-ruby
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20141231T173138Z
UID:...
DTSTART:20141011T081000
DTEND:20141012T081000
CLASS:PRIVATE
DESCRIPTION:Blah blah blah
SUMMARY:Secrets of Alchemy
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:EMAIL
TRIGGER:-P1D
DESCRIPTION:Event reminder
SUMMARY:Alarm notification
ATTENDEE:
ATTENDEE:
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Don't pay attention to end time, but in either one, the time part of datetime changes. I'd like to make it display correct time somehow.

Answer (score 3):

Add in Gemfile:-

```
gem 'tzinfo'
gem 'tzinfo-data'
```

Then make changes as:-

```
require 'icalendar/tzinfo'
require 'tzinfo'

cal = Icalendar::Calendar.new

event_start = DateTime.new 2014, 12, 30, 19, 34, 00
event_end = DateTime.new 2014, 12, 30, 21, 34, 00

tzid = "America/Chicago"
tz = TZInfo::Timezone.get tzid
timezone = tz.ical_timezone event_start
cal.add_timezone timezone

cal.event do |e|
  e.dtstart = Icalendar::Values::DateTime.new event_start, 'tzid' => tzid
  e.dtend   = Icalendar::Values::DateTime.new event_end, 'tzid' => tzid
end
```

Send this ics as attachment in email as:--

```
attachments["schedule.ics"] = {:mime_type => 'text/calendar',
  :content => cal.to_ical}
```

**Note:-**

`event_start` and `event_end` should be taken in the same time zone as `tzid`, then it will automatically convert the correct time accordingly to the timezone in which this ics file will be open.

Comment: Hmm... I just tried this and it didn't work for me. It still does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

In `application.rb` I uncommented the line `config.time_zone = 'My Time Zone'` .
Now it works.

Referred to this guide: http://www.elabs.se/blog/36-working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails